# How to update machine type of gcp instnace using nodejs client library

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, client-library

I have a node server which handles gcp instance operations. I am trying to update the machine type of a existing running instance. I don't want to update any other properties like disk size or anything.

```
    
    const computeClient = new Compute.InstancesClient({
      projectId: "project",
      keyFilename: "keyfile",
    });
        let resource = {
          instance: "testinstance",
          instanceResource: {
            machineType : "zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/e2-standard-4",
            name: "testinstance"
          },
          project: "project",
          zone : "us-central1-a"
        }
        const resp1 = await computeClient.update(resource);
```

When I try to run above code this error occurs

```
    Stacktrace:
    ==================== 
    Error: Invalid value for field 'resource.disks': ''. No disks are specified.
        at Function.parseHttpError (////node_modules/google-gax/build/src/googleError.js:49:37)
        at decodeResponse (///node_modules/google-gax/build/src/fallbackRest.js:72:49)
        at ////node_modules/google-gax/build/src/fallbackServiceStub.js:90:42
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

    node version : v16.14.0 
    @google-cloud/compute version : 3.1.2
```

Any solution ? Any code sample to update machine type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to update your instance's machine type you should use the `setMachineType` method directly which is meant for this specifically. See example below:

```
// Imports the Compute library
const {InstancesClient} = require('@google-cloud/compute').v1;

// Instantiates a client
const computeClient = new InstancesClient();
const instance = "instance-name";
const instancesSetMachineTypeRequestResource = {machineType: "zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/n1-standard-1"}
const project = "project-id";
const zone = "us-central1-a";

async function callSetMachineType() {
  // Construct request
  const request = {
    instance,
    instancesSetMachineTypeRequestResource,
    project,
    zone,
  };

  // Run request
  const response = await computeClient.setMachineType(request);
  console.log(response);
}

callSetMachineType();
```

Note that machine type can only be changed on a `TERMINATED` instance as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance#changing_a_machine_type). You'll need to first ensure the instance is stopped or stop it in your code prior to updating machine type. More details on available methods [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/latest/compute/v1.instancesclient#_google_cloud_compute_v1_InstancesClient_stop_member_3_).

Comment: Your answer does not show how to initialize **instancesSetMachineTypeRequestResource** to a machine type name such as **n1-standard-1**. As written the code will fail. The Google documentation is terrible on this item.

Comment: @john, I couldn't find any documentation explaining it indeed but the **instancesSetMachineTypeRequestResource** ultimately represents the request body of the corresponding API call documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setMachineType#request-body). I've requested a documentation update on these obscure parameters. I've also updated my answer with a working example (tested on my side).

Comment: SO we Can't update machine type without stopping the instance. In older versions it was possible. Thanks for the answer@LundinCast